# Reading NV chart data (.bsb and .eap) with QGIS?

Tags: qgis, import

I have some data from NV charts. As it looks like the data is contained in .bsb and .eap files. Is there a possibility to implement these data in QGIS as raster as a background? Loading the .bsb data directly seems not possible. Loading the .eap data works but there is only black and white lines and nothings looks like a map.

This nautical chart data seems to be different from NOAA data as no .kap files exist.

Data can be read using the following software:
nv charts App, Chart Navigator professional, or Chart Navigator Standard.

Comment: Can you link to some sample data? Have you searched for any docs about the file format or what you can do with them? Do you know what software can read them?

Comment: @Spacedman unfortunatly I can not as I am not allowed to share the data. I thought maybe somebody has worked before with this kind of nautical chart data.

Comment: @ AndreJ I don't think it is the same as NOAA data as my data has no .kap files. It just might be the same ending, or NOAA added the .kap files to make it readable in GIS

Comment: @Alex you are right. Downloading data from https://nvcharts.com/shop/de/download and unpacking them, it seems the BSB is just a text-based attribute file for EAP files.

Comment: @andrej What data did you download? All I see on that page are lots of .EXE files, manuals in PDF format, waypoints2019.txt, and a broken link to a zip file.

Comment: You can extract the exe files with 7zip to a new folder. In the chart subfolder you see the bsb and eap files. The eap look similar to the NOAA kap files. Maybe they did something different in writing them. This may affect the way the built-in palette is used. The cell values don't correspond to the palette table.

Answer (score 2):

BSB and EAP are not common GIS file formats. According to the [NV Charts FAQ](https://nvcharts.com/shop/de/faq), the data are intended to be used in the NV Charts app, but they can also be opened in the following programs:

> NV Chart Navigator Lite, Standard, Professional;  Rosepoint NS; 
>      Stentec; SW & N; Tiki; GPSNavX; Memory-Map; Euronav; Fugawi; GPS 32;
>      Touratech; expedition; Nautibus; Free Technics; OziExplorer; Navkom;
>      Barcosoft (Linux); Hatje computer science; Imray; Global Mapper; compegps;
>      PolarNavy; ConfiTek; OpenCPN; AF tracker; PC-Navigo

**BSB files**

QGIS uses the GDAL library to translate geospatial data formats. Here's what it says about BSB files on GDAL's "[Supported raster formats](https://www.gdal.org/frmt_various.html#BSB)" documentation page:

> BSB -- Maptech/NOAA BSB Nautical Chart Format
>
> BSB Nautical Chart format is supported for read access, including reading the colour table and the reference points (as GCPs). **Note that the .BSB files cannot be selected directly. Instead select the .KAP files.** Versions 1.1, 2.0 and 3.0 have been tested successfully.
>
> This driver should also support GEO/NOS format as supplied by Softchart. These files normally have the extension .nos with associated .geo files containing georeferencing ... the .geo files are currently ignored.
>
> This driver is based on work by Mike Higgins. See the frmts/bsb/bsb_read.c files for details on patents affecting BSB format.
>
> Starting with GDAL 1.6.0, it is possible to select an alternate color palette via the BSB_PALETTE configuration option. The default value is RGB. Other common values that can be found are : DAY, DSK, NGT, NGR, GRY, PRC, PRG...
>
> NOTE: Implemented as gdal/frmts/bsb/bsbdataset.cpp.

As you can see from this description, the GDAL definition of BSB files assumes they are the format provided by NOAA, which comes with a KAP file.

**EAP files**

EAP files are not mentioned on either the raster or [supported vector format](https://www.gdal.org/ogr_formats.html) pages.

You mentioned that

> Loading the .eap data works but there is only black and white lines and nothings looks like a map.

Have a look at the attribute table for hidden information that might be associated with these lines. QGIS allows you to [control line styling](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/style_library.html#configuring-a-symbol) based on attribute information. Try applying a Categorized, Graduated or Rule-Based style.

Comment: Thanks, but as I read it I think my nautical .bsb files from NV charts maight not be the same. And the .eap files don't seem to be Enterprise Architect files. Changing the style doesn't really help to make anythink readable.

Comment: What information are you trying to make readable on the map? If the vector features have attributes (as @AndreJ suggested that bsb files contain attributes for the vector features in the eap files), you can use those attributes as text labels.

Comment: I doubt that the EAP files mentioned on stackoverflow have anything to do with this topic. BTW this is raster data, not vector data.

Comment: @AndreJ I suspect you're right; I deleted that link from my answer.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answer by @csk:

`gdalinfo` is able to read the metadata of the EAP file correctly (georeference and palette) using the BSB driver, but `gdal_translate` fails on transforming it to another format (even with using BSB_IGNORE_LINENUMBERS configure option).

So what you can do is:

- wrap a vrt file around it. See https://gdal.org/gdal_vrttut.html#gdal_vrttut_raw You have to experiment with the offset and line length.
- Look into https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/gdal/frmts/bsb/bsb_read.c and write your own code to read the file.